# Pattern matching with type parameter bounded to final class

Tags: scala, type-erasure

Here is an example

```
def maybeeq[A <: String](x: A):A = x match {
  case z:A => x
}
```

It produced the following error message during compilation

> Error:(27, 12) scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
>   found   : A
>    required: String
>       case z:A => x

I can put any final class into A's bound to reproduce the error.

Why this compiles for non-final classes but fails on the final? Why type erasure not just replace A with String?

Edited:

Note: such bound allows me to pass String-typed value to 'x' parameter. So 'x' can be just a String and don't have to be subtype of string, so I'm not asking compiler to compile method with incorrect signature. In the real-world code I would just put String instead on A parameter, but from the experimental perspective I'm interested why such extra restriction on top of existing restriction (based on final class nature) is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TBH this is a question about compiler design which can only be answered by those who implemented such check

There is [a test](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/test/files/neg/t3015.scala) in compiler test suite that [requires such error to be shown](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/test/files/neg/t3015.check). It has something to do with type information being discarded to a point where a concrete type cannot be assigned to variable, but the reasons for that cannot be understood from `git blame` of that test.

---

I'll point out, however, that there is still a number of ways to satisfy `A <: String` without `A` being known at compile time to be a `String`. For one, `Null` and `Nothing` satisfy that, being at the bottom of Scala type hierarchy. Those two are explicitly disallowed at type matching. The other example is a bit more involved:

```
val UhOh: { type T <: String } = new { type T = String }
implicitly[UhOh.T <:< String] // satisfies type bound
implicitly[UhOh.T =:= String] // won't compile - compiler cannot prove the type equality
```

This is similar to some newtyping patterns, e.g. `shapeless.tag`

Out of all these possibilities, only one that can do anything reasonable is when `A =:= String` because `String` is the only type that can be actually checked at runtime. Oh, except when you use generic type in match - that does not work at all (not without `ClassTag` in scope at least) because such types are eliminated by erasure.

Comment: btw, it seems that test you mentioned is related to the issue when existential type cannot be expanded to local context without type member presence and thus can't be used in pattern matching. I'm not 100% sure about that, but if you are interested you can find some explanation here https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/16/method-equiv.html

Answer (score 1):

**Final class** cannot be extended.so for `def maybeeq[A <: String](x: A)` is not a correct syntax, since `String` is `final`, there should not have any **subtype** extend from `String`. the compiler smartly point out this issue.

Comment: but x param can be just a String and this passes the bound check. I don't understand why compiler need to restrict such case.

Comment: `A <: String` means `A` is a subtype of `String`, Since `String` is the final type,  `A` only can be `String` type, so why don't use `String` type directly?

Comment: From the practical perspective you are right, but I'm wondering why this extra restriction is needed. I suppose that such restrictions usually made to prevent developers from making runtime mistakes, but in this specific case such mistake is not possible due to final nature of the class. So it looks like one more restriction on top of existing restriction that doesn't make any practical sense.

Comment: @chengpohi Actually it's not true that "`A` only can be `String` type":   `type T <: String;
  maybeeq[T](???);
  maybeeq[Nothing](???)`

Comment: @chengpohi Moreover `maybeeq[String with Int](???);
  maybeeq[String with Cloneable](???)` ...

Comment: @dmytro-mitin For the sake of justice I would note that we just can't create an instance of any of such types because there is no way to create a class extending "String with Int"

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko I don't mean to argue, I just noticed inaccuracy. Let's not confuse classes and types (in Scala ["there are more types than classes"](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html)). If existence of instance is important we can do `maybeeq[Null](null)`.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko BTW, we also forgot literal types: `maybeeq["a"]("a")` in Typelevel Scala or ``maybeeq[Witness.`"a"`.T]("a")`` in Shapeless or `val a = "a";  maybeeq[a.type](a)` in Lightbend Scala (standard Scala).